# Let's make a question template for repair-quote consultation

Tags: discussion, scope, asking-questions

### Motivation

Many moons ago, I took my vehicle to the dealership to diagnose an electrical gremlin. They recommended a rather expensive repair - replace the fuel pump - which did not fix the issue at all. After re-evaluating the vehicle, they simply cleaned some electrical contacts and the issue went away.

Many people will be in a similar situation of naïvete and despair when *Something Bad* happens and the site has its fair share of questions along the lines of "*Please help!*", "*Am I being ripped off?*", "*Does this repair sound reasonable?*"

It makes sense to invest some thought into how we can help them to help us help them, especially since many questions can go unanswered due to missing information.

### Strategy

The purpose of this meta post is to craft a list of information which should be included in the question.

Here is what I have so far:

- identifying information that is crucial to any diagnosis (e.g. vehicle make, model, year)
- vehicle background - symptoms or events that led to the owner/user to realize that something is wrong (e.g. wheel wobble, misfire)
- information which would be nice to have (e.g. DTC's, fuel trims)
- information pertaining to the repair quote (e.g. recommendation, list of parts to replace/repair - a printed copy of the quote would be ideal)

---

Let's see if we can put together a decent template for such types of issues. Ultimately, I would like to be able to use this post as a guideline for a new/inexperienced user who hasn't furbished sufficient information to show them what crucial information they're missing.

Comment: As for your particular issue `replace the fuel pump - which did not fix the issue at all` you shouldn't have paid for, or should have be refunded for the fuel pump replacement. Only paying for what actually fixed the car.

Comment: Why so many downvotes? Does this question not- _show any research effort; it is unclear and not usefull_?

Comment: @chilljeet : I don't think on meta it means that. It's more an indication of disapproval - "Let's not go down this path"

Comment: I get that. I just think it's incorrect usage nonetheless. More so cause it's in Meta, where one can discuss and question the very identity of the group itself.

Answer (score 8):

Let's not, I don't think those questions should be on topic.

Those questions fall into the same problems as price-shopping assistance, they will become obsolete, and they are unlikely to help anyone else.

I think we do need some sort of information you have mention in the [How to Ask](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) portion of the help section for *all* questions. There are way too many

> My car is [insert vague incomplete description here] please help!

that get closed as unclear what you are asking.

As for the am I being ripped off, is this repair reasonable I think a single generic post to address those questions would answer 99% of them. Some of the topics covered in that post would be:

- Get a second opinion
- Get a second and third quote
- Have the tech explain why your car needs what it needs
- Have the tech show you the old parts

Comment: It may be okay to have well-moderated wiki posts for questions like these, but I want to say I agree that these kinds of questions are off-topic.